# Instagram browser not loading content

Tags: c#, typescript, react-native, umbraco, umbraco-ucommerce

I am currently developing a website using Umbraco and uCommerce. At the moment, I am experiencing an issue with Instagram.
When I link to the website from my Instagram story, and Instagram opens their browser and redirects to the website, only the header and footer from the site is shown. The rest of the content, which is fetched from Umbraco and uCommerce, is not loading in the Instagram browser.

I have tried whitelisting different crawler bots in my appsettings but without any success. Has anyone experienced this issue, or does anyone know the name of the Instagram bot that crawls the site?

Answer (score 0):

This is certainly not related to Umbraco or uCommerce, but to your HTML and CSS. If you look at the same URL in a normal browser you should see the url. Also check on mobile view in your desktop brower.